# Android - ActionBar set elevation programmatically

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-toolbar

**styles.xml**

```
 style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
 parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"

 style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
 parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
```

**fragment_container.xml**

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

I add toolbar using below code in onCreate callback

var pageLayoutContainer = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(NativeSFR.layout.page_container_layout, null);

```
fragmentLayoutContainer.findViewById(R.id.fragmentRootLayout);
toolbar = fragmentLayoutContainer.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
actionBar = activity.getSupportActionBar();
```

I want to remove shadow under the toolbar. But below code doesn't work for me. My device api level bigger than 21.

```
actionBar.setElevation(0);
```

Comment: Try android:elevation="0dp" in toolbar, and make sure havent set it in the style AppTheme.PopupOverlay

Comment: I removed AppBarLayout.  And I set elevation of the toolbar as 0. It works

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
AppBarLayout appBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.appBarLayout);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    appBarLayout.setElevation(getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.elevation));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I removed AppBarLayout. And I set elevation of the toolbar as 0 at runtime. It works for me.

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

But I couldn't understand why elevation 0 doesn't work(with AppBarLayout).

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorYellow"
            android:elevation="4dp"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        android:background="@color/colorYellow"
        android:id="@+id/page_layout"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
ViewCompat.setElevation(View, int);
```

or

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

Comment: Please check my question text. I have tested setElevation(0) but it doesn't work.

Comment: you tried with actionBar.setElevation(0); have you tried my answer

Comment: getSupportActionBar return value assigned to actionBar. :)  I have tested in onViewCreated activity.getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);